# how to add dynamic checkbox inside web api response?

Tags: android, json, checkbox, dialog

here is my code where I am getting my response in multiple timing slots  I want to create multiple checkboxes according to time response here is my code :

```
  @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.e("@@TimeApi", response);
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray jsonArray = objData.getJSONArray("time");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        String time = jsonArray.getString(i);
                        Log.e("@@Time", time);
                        final List<String> timeList = Arrays.asList(time);


                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

inside for loop, I am getting time now I need to put times in dialog with checkboxes

In the log I am getting a response like this time may come in multiple

Answer (score 0):

In AlertDialog you need to set list in setMultipleChoiceItems, check the following code

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Log.e("@@TimeApi", response);
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray jsonArray = objData.getJSONArray("time");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    String[] timeList = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                    boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[jsonArray.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        String time = jsonArray.getString(i);
                        Log.e("@@Time", time);
                        timeList[i] = time;
                        checkedItems[i] = false;
                    }

                    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(timeList, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            Log.i("@@Time", "position" + which + " state " + isChecked);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: here How to set checkbox according to time

Comment: according to time means?

Comment: in response i am getting time in json array

Comment: you want to sort based on time?

Comment: i want to add dynamic time with checkbox

Comment: but what does dynamic time means?